# Issue running spark-shell with yarn client, ERROR client.TransportClient: Failed to send RPC

Tags: windows, apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, spark-shell

I am trying to setup hadoop 3.1.2 with spark in windows. i have started hdfs cluster and i am able to create,copy files in hdfs. When i try to start spark-shell with yarn i am facing

```
ERROR cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Diagnostics message: Uncaught exception: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult:
        at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:227)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRefByURI(RpcEnv.scala:101)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRef(RpcEnv.scala:109)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.runExecutorLauncher(ApplicationMaster.scala:544)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:264)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$3.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:875)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$3.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:874)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1729)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$.main(ApplicationMaster.scala:874)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ExecutorLauncher$.main(ApplicationMaster.scala:906)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ExecutorLauncher.main(ApplicationMaster.scala)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to send RPC RPC 7406367420263248997 to DESKTOP-TVBSANL.bbrouter/192.168.1.38:49691: io.netty.channel.socket.ChannelOutputShutdownException: Channel output shutdown
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClient$RpcChannelListener.handleFailure(TransportClient.java:362)
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClient$StdChannelListener.operationComplete(TransportClient.java:339)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:507)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:500)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:479)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:420)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:122)
        at io.netty.util.internal.PromiseNotificationUtil.tryFailure(PromiseNotificationUtil.java:64)
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundBuffer.safeFail(ChannelOutboundBuffer.java:680)
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundBuffer.remove0(ChannelOutboundBuffer.java:294)
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundBuffer.failFlushed(ChannelOutboundBuffer.java:617)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.closeOutboundBufferForShutdown(AbstractChannel.java:627)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.shutdownOutput(AbstractChannel.java:620)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush0(AbstractChannel.java:893)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.flush0(AbstractNioChannel.java:313)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush(AbstractChannel.java:847)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.flush(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1264)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:770)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:762)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:743)
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.flush(ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.java:115)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:770)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:762)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:743)
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelDuplexHandler.flush(ChannelDuplexHandler.java:117)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:770)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:762)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.access$1500(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:35)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$WriteAndFlushTask.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:1116)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$AbstractWriteTask.run(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:1050)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:399)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:464)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:131)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:138)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: io.netty.channel.socket.ChannelOutputShutdownException: Channel output shutdown
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.shutdownOutput(AbstractChannel.java:587)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.network.util.AbstractFileRegion.transferred()J
        at org.apache.spark.network.util.AbstractFileRegion.transfered(AbstractFileRegion.java:28)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel.doWrite(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:228)
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doWrite(NioSocketChannel.java:282)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush0(AbstractChannel.java:879)
        ... 21 more

2020-03-28 11:32:11,608 WARN cluster.YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: Attempted to request executors before the AM has registered!
```

when checked with yarn logs

```
2020-03-28 11:32:11,487 ERROR client.TransportClient: Failed to send RPC RPC 7406367420263248997 to DESKTOP-TVBSANL.bbrouter/192.168.1.38:49691: io.netty.channel.socket.ChannelOutputShutdownException: Channel output shutdown
io.netty.channel.socket.ChannelOutputShutdownException: Channel output shutdown
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.shutdownOutput(AbstractChannel.java:587)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush0(AbstractChannel.java:893)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.flush0(AbstractNioChannel.java:313)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush(AbstractChannel.java:847)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.flush(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1264)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:770)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:762)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:743)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.flush(ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.java:115)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:770)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:762)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:743)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelDuplexHandler.flush(ChannelDuplexHandler.java:117)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:770)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:762)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.access$1500(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:35)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$WriteAndFlushTask.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:1116)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$AbstractWriteTask.run(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:1050)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:399)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:464)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:131)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:138)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.network.util.AbstractFileRegion.transferred()J
    at org.apache.spark.network.util.AbstractFileRegion.transfered(AbstractFileRegion.java:28)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel.doWrite(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:228)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doWrite(NioSocketChannel.java:282)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush0(AbstractChannel.java:879)
    ... 21 more
2020-03-28 11:32:11,494 ERROR yarn.ApplicationMaster: Uncaught exception: 
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult: 
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:227)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRefByURI(RpcEnv.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRef(RpcEnv.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.runExecutorLauncher(ApplicationMaster.scala:544)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$3.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:875)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$3.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:874)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1729)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$.main(ApplicationMaster.scala:874)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ExecutorLauncher$.main(ApplicationMaster.scala:906)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ExecutorLauncher.main(ApplicationMaster.scala)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to send RPC RPC 7406367420263248997 to DESKTOP-TVBSANL.bbrouter/192.168.1.38:49691: io.netty.channel.socket.ChannelOutputShutdownException: Channel output shutdown
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClient$RpcChannelListener.handleFailure(TransportClient.java:362)
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClient$StdChannelListener.operationComplete(TransportClient.java:339)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:507)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:500)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:479)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:420)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:122)
    at io.netty.util.internal.PromiseNotificationUtil.tryFailure(PromiseNotificationUtil.java:64)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundBuffer.safeFail(ChannelOutboundBuffer.java:680)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundBuffer.remove0(ChannelOutboundBuffer.java:294)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundBuffer.failFlushed(ChannelOutboundBuffer.java:617)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.closeOutboundBufferForShutdown(AbstractChannel.java:627)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.shutdownOutput(AbstractChannel.java:620)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush0(AbstractChannel.java:893)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.flush0(AbstractNioChannel.java:313)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush(AbstractChannel.java:847)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.flush(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1264)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:770)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:762)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:743)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.flush(ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.java:115)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:770)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:762)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:743)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelDuplexHandler.flush(ChannelDuplexHandler.java:117)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:770)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:762)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.access$1500(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:35)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$WriteAndFlushTask.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:1116)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$AbstractWriteTask.run(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:1050)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:399)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:464)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:131)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:138)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: io.netty.channel.socket.ChannelOutputShutdownException: Channel output shutdown
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.shutdownOutput(AbstractChannel.java:587)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.network.util.AbstractFileRegion.transferred()J
    at org.apache.spark.network.util.AbstractFileRegion.transfered(AbstractFileRegion.java:28)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel.doWrite(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:228)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doWrite(NioSocketChannel.java:282)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush0(AbstractChannel.java:879)
    ... 21 more
2020-03-28 11:32:11,497 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Final app status: FAILED, exitCode: 10, (reason: Uncaught exception: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult: 
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:227)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRefByURI(RpcEnv.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRef(RpcEnv.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.runExecutorLauncher(ApplicationMaster.scala:544)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$3.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:875)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$3.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:874)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1729)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$.main(ApplicationMaster.scala:874)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ExecutorLauncher$.main(ApplicationMaster.scala:906)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ExecutorLauncher.main(ApplicationMaster.scala)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to send RPC RPC 7406367420263248997 to DESKTOP-TVBSANL.bbrouter/192.168.1.38:49691: io.netty.channel.socket.ChannelOutputShutdownException: Channel output shutdown
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClient$RpcChannelListener.handleFailure(TransportClient.java:362)
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClient$StdChannelListener.operationComplete(TransportClient.java:339)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:507)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:500)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:479)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:420)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:122)
    at io.netty.util.internal.PromiseNotificationUtil.tryFailure(PromiseNotificationUtil.java:64)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundBuffer.safeFail(ChannelOutboundBuffer.java:680)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundBuffer.remove0(ChannelOutboundBuffer.java:294)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundBuffer.failFlushed(ChannelOutboundBuffer.java:617)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.closeOutboundBufferForShutdown(AbstractChannel.java:627)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.shutdownOutput(AbstractChannel.java:620)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush0(AbstractChannel.java:893)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.flush0(AbstractNioChannel.java:313)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush(AbstractChannel.java:847)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.flush(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1264)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:770)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:762)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:743)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.flush(ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.java:115)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:770)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:762)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:743)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelDuplexHandler.flush(ChannelDuplexHandler.java:117)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:770)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:762)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.access$1500(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:35)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$WriteAndFlushTask.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:1116)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$AbstractWriteTask.run(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:1050)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:399)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:464)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:131)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:138)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: io.netty.channel.socket.ChannelOutputShutdownException: Channel output shutdown
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.shutdownOutput(AbstractChannel.java:587)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.network.util.AbstractFileRegion.transferred()J
    at org.apache.spark.network.util.AbstractFileRegion.transfered(AbstractFileRegion.java:28)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel.doWrite(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:228)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doWrite(NioSocketChannel.java:282)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush0(AbstractChannel.java:879)
    ... 21 more
)
2020-03-28 11:32:11,505 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Unregistering ApplicationMaster with FAILED (diag message: Uncaught exception: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult: 
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:227)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRefByURI(RpcEnv.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRef(RpcEnv.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.runExecutorLauncher(ApplicationMaster.scala:544)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$3.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:875)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$3.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:874)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1729)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$.main(ApplicationMaster.scala:874)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ExecutorLauncher$.main(ApplicationMaster.scala:906)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ExecutorLauncher.main(ApplicationMaster.scala)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to send RPC RPC 7406367420263248997 to DESKTOP-TVBSANL.bbrouter/192.168.1.38:49691: io.netty.channel.socket.ChannelOutputShutdownException: Channel output shutdown
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClient$RpcChannelListener.handleFailure(TransportClient.java:362)
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClient$StdChannelListener.operationComplete(TransportClient.java:339)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:507)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:500)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:479)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:420)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:122)
    at io.netty.util.internal.PromiseNotificationUtil.tryFailure(PromiseNotificationUtil.java:64)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundBuffer.safeFail(ChannelOutboundBuffer.java:680)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundBuffer.remove0(ChannelOutboundBuffer.java:294)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundBuffer.failFlushed(ChannelOutboundBuffer.java:617)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.closeOutboundBufferForShutdown(AbstractChannel.java:627)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.shutdownOutput(AbstractChannel.java:620)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush0(AbstractChannel.java:893)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.flush0(AbstractNioChannel.java:313)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush(AbstractChannel.java:847)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.flush(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1264)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:770)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:762)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:743)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.flush(ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.java:115)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:770)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:762)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:743)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelDuplexHandler.flush(ChannelDuplexHandler.java:117)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:770)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:762)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.access$1500(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:35)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$WriteAndFlushTask.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:1116)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$AbstractWriteTask.run(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:1050)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:399)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:464)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:131)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:138)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: io.netty.channel.socket.ChannelOutputShutdownException: Channel output shutdown
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.shutdownOutput(AbstractChannel.java:587)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.network.util.AbstractFileRegion.transferred()J
    at org.apache.spark.network.util.AbstractFileRegion.transfered(AbstractFileRegion.java:28)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel.doWrite(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:228)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doWrite(NioSocketChannel.java:282)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush0(AbstractChannel.java:879)
    ... 21 more
)
2020-03-28 11:32:11,526 INFO impl.AMRMClientImpl: Waiting for application to be successfully unregistered.
2020-03-28 11:32:11,729 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Deleting staging directory hdfs://localhost:9000/user/Andrew/.sparkStaging/application_1585375241853_0002
2020-03-28 11:32:12,225 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
```

I have even added the following properties in spark conf

```
spark.driver.extraJavaOptions -Dhdp.version=3.1.2
spark.yarn.am.extraJavaOptions -Dhdp.version=3.1.2
```

these in yarn-site

```
    <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.pmem-check-enabled</name>
    <value>false</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled</name>
    <value>false</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.vmem-pmem-ratio</name>
    <value>5</value>
</property>
```

My cluster is a single node cluster. Windows os with 16gb ram and 500 GB HDD. The following is my hdfs report

```
Configured Capacity: 1000203087872 (931.51 GB)
Present Capacity: 252250412093 (234.93 GB)
DFS Remaining: 252011880448 (234.70 GB)
DFS Used: 238531645 (227.48 MB)
DFS Used%: 0.09%
Replicated Blocks:
        Under replicated blocks: 0
        Blocks with corrupt replicas: 0
        Missing blocks: 0
        Missing blocks (with replication factor 1): 0
        Low redundancy blocks with highest priority to recover: 0
        Pending deletion blocks: 0
Erasure Coded Block Groups:
        Low redundancy block groups: 0
        Block groups with corrupt internal blocks: 0
        Missing block groups: 0
        Low redundancy blocks with highest priority to recover: 0
        Pending deletion blocks: 0

-------------------------------------------------
Live datanodes (1):

Name: 127.0.0.1:9866 (127.0.0.1)
Hostname: ##################
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 1000203087872 (931.51 GB)
DFS Used: 238531645 (227.48 MB)
Non DFS Used: 747952675779 (696.59 GB)
DFS Remaining: 252011880448 (234.70 GB)
DFS Used%: 0.02%
DFS Remaining%: 25.20%
Configured Cache Capacity: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used: 0 (0 B)
Cache Remaining: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used%: 100.00%
Cache Remaining%: 0.00%
Xceivers: 1
Last contact: Sat Mar 28 11:48:14 IST 2020
Last Block Report: Sat Mar 28 11:30:44 IST 2020
Num of Blocks: 248
```

I have been at this for 2 days now. would appreciate help.

Thanks in advance.